# What kind of transformation are $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given are the two transformations 3D:

$$M_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \,\,\,
M_2=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) & -\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) & 0\\ 
\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) & \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

What is the kind of transformation of $M_1$, what of $M_2$?

If something like that was asked in an exam, how would this be done because I'm not sure if I understand it correctly?

I understand it like this: What two things were multiplied so you get $M_1$. Or what do I need to do here? I really don't understand what needs to be done :/

Comment: If you don't know this fromthe forms of the matrices, try multiplying the matrix by a few test points, of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}$$

And see what you would have to do to the original point to get the image point.

Comment: What two thing were multiplied to get $M_1$ sounds like a good way to go.  What is the answer?

Comment: What apparently you don't understand is the fact that, to a matrix, is associated a transformation. For example $\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\ 
y'\\ 
z'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$ generates an enlargment by $2$ : this is what they are asking you. In other cases, it can be rotation, a symmetry etc.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think I understand now what is asked. With first matrix if I for example do $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$$ then the result of this is in general of this form $$\begin{pmatrix}
y\\ 
x+y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$$

And now what they want from me is to name what happened ("rotation" / "scaling" / "shearing" etc.)? Did I understand this right?

Edit: Hmm I think my $y$ value is not correct ^^

Comment: That's it. For example, $M_2$ is associated to the $\pi/2$ rotation around $z$ axis.