# What kind of transformation is this matrix refering to?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, computer-science

> Given is the 3D transformation $$M_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\  3 &
> 0 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> What kind of transformation is $M_1$?

I've used several different points \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}

and did operations with it $$\begin{pmatrix}
x'\\ 
y'\\ 
z'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\  3 &
0 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}$$

By several test-inputs I know that the solution is always in the form of \begin{pmatrix}
y\\ 
3x\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}

So basically the $z$ value never changes, but the $x$ value is swapped with the $y$ value and the $x$ value which now is the $y$ value got multiplied by $3$.

I'm really missing the name of the transformation here because it's neither a scaling for me, nor a rotation or a shearing... It's more like a mixture of several transformations (called affine transformation?)? Or there is not really a name for this? It's very confusing I'm sorry if it is :(

Comment: [deja vu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147020/what-kind-of-transformation-are-m-1-and-m-2)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yees:D In my previous question I didn't even know what it was all about, what kind of answer is expected and what is being asked- that's what my first topic was about. Now I do but I thought I needed another topic for this because now I got an idea of it and a solution which I'm not sure about^^ I hope that is ok but if not please tell me and I delete this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$M_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\  3 &
0 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\  0 &
3 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\  1 &
0 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Looks like a reflection in $y=x$ together with a scaling.